# Differentiable function $f(x)=4x^7 −14x^4 +30x−17$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am trying to prove that the function $f:\Bbb R→\Bbb R$, $f(x)=4x^7 −14x^4 +30x−17$,is injective. To do this I need to prove it is differentiable from first principles. I can then prove its derivative is strictly increasing to show it is injective. Any help on the proof that it's differentiable would be great, especially in what delta to choose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we can  evaluate a derivative, our function is differentiable.

Also, $$f'(x)=28x^6-56x^3+30=28\left(x^6-2x^3+\frac{15}{14}\right)=28\left((x^3-1)^2+\frac{1}{14}\right)>0.$$
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=$$
$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{4((x+h)^7-x^7)-14((x+h)^4-x^4)+30(x+h-x)}{h}=$$
$$=4(7x^6)-14(4x^3)+30=28x^6-56x^3+30.$$

Comment: I understand this part but our course needs to use the definition f'(a)=lim(x tends to a) of (f(x)-f(a))

Comment: @agirlbadatmath I evaluated the derivative by the definition. See now.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomials are always continuous and differentiable $\forall x \in R$
Here use $\frac{d x^n}{dx}=n x^{n-1}$, Also use the distributivity of $\frac{d}{dx}$ as :$\frac{d}{dx}[ a f(x)+ b g(x)] =a\frac{d}{dx} f(x)+ b\frac{d}{dx} g(x)$, to get
$$\frac{d}{dx}(4x^7-14x^4+30 x-17)= 4 \frac{d}{dx} x^7-14 \frac{d}{dx} x^4 +30\frac{d}{dx}x- \frac{d}{dx}17= 28 x^6-56 x^3 +30. $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=4x^7-14x^4+30x-17$. Then $$f'(x)=28x^6-42x^3+30=28U^2-42U+30,$$
where $U=x^3$.

Since the discriminant of $28U^2-42U+30$ is negative, the sign of $f'$ won't change.

Answer (score 0):

The OP is asking for a first-principles derivation of the derivative  of a specific polynomial. Here's one way to do it, using the algebraic identity $(x^n-y^n)=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y^2+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$.

If $f(x)=4x^7-14x^4+30x-17$, then

$$\begin{align}
{f(x)-f(a)\over x-a}
&={4(x^7-a^7)-14(x^4-a^4)+30(x-a)\over x-a}\\
&={4(x-a)(x^6+x^5a+x^4a^2+x^3a^3+x^2a^4+xa^5+a^6)-14(x-a)(x^3+x^2a+xa^2+a^3)+30(x-a)\over x-a}\\
&=4(x^6+x^5a+x^4a^2+x^3a^3+x^2a^4+xa^5+a^6)-14(x^3+x^2a+xa^2+a^3)+30
\end{align}$$

hence

$$\begin{align}
f'(a)&=\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)-f(a)\over x-a}\\
&=\lim_{x\to a}(4(x^6+x^5a+x^4a^2+x^3a^3+x^2a^4+xa^5+a^6)-14(x^3+x^2a+xa^2+a^3)+30)\\
&=4(a^6+a^5a+a^4a^2+a^3a^3+a^2a^4+aa^5+a^6)-14(a^3+a^2a+aa^2+a^3)+30\\
&=4\cdot7a^6-14\cdot4a^3+30\\
&=28a^6-56a^3+30
\end{align}$$